# Android set ImageView full screen with transparent imageviews inside

Tags: android, imageview

I have this xml layout that sets an image to the ImageView. I also have 3 other imagviews that works as retake, cancel and save. I want to have the imageview fullscreen and the other imageviews showing transparent on that imageview.

I tried with many different settings but can't accomplish this. Here is a screenshot and the xml layout. How can I set the imageview to fullscreen with the other imageviews (with the onclick methods) showing transparent in the fullscreen imageview?

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"

android:background="@color/grayA"

android:orientation="vertical" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layerType="software"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/backgroundLinear"
        android:src="@drawable/nature_1"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        />
    <ImageView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:src="@drawable/whittakepic"
        android:onClick="launchCamera"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:layout_weight="0.05" />

    <ImageView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageTest"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/whiteok"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
        android:layout_weight="0.05" />

    <ImageView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:src="@drawable/whitex"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
        android:layout_weight="0.05" />





</FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Does your TouchImageView extend ImageView?  If so, you will need to set a scaleType property on it that allows it to crop the image if it doesn't scale to exactly the size of the ImageView.

Comment: I edited and changed the TouchImageView to ImageView so it's not confusing. It still looks the same even if I have an Imageview there. I want the imageview set to fullscreeen and the other imageviews inside that imageview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure of your layout is fine. The image view is filling the entire layout. The issue is that your image height/width ratio prevents it from filling the entire screen without distorting or cropping the image. Try adding:

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

to your ImageView identified as "backgroundLinear".